# Fatal Error of Database when Upgrade GitLab 8.11 to 8.13

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, upgrade

I have failed in upgrading Gitlab from version 8.11.2 to the latest version (8.11.7, 8.12 and 8.13). Here is the output when I execute the commandline `dpkg -i gitlab-ce_8.13.1-ce.0_amd64.deb`.

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.3.6/lib/omnibus-ctl.
rb:533: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt/gitlab/bin in PATH, mode 04077
7
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.12.15/lib/chef/mixin/path_
sanity.rb:25: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt/gitlab/bin in PATH, mode
 040777
/sbin/init: unrecognized option '--version'
dpkg: error processing package gitlab-ce (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab-ce
```

and the detailed error is shown as below:

```
(Reading database ... 169188 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack gitlab-ce_8.13.1-ce.0_amd64.deb ...
gitlab preinstall: Automatically backing up only the GitLab SQL database (excluding everything else!)
Dumping database ... 
Dumping PostgreSQL database gitlabhq_production ... [DONE]
done
Dumping repositories ...
[SKIPPED]
Dumping uploads ... 
[SKIPPED]
Dumping builds ... 
[SKIPPED]
Dumping artifacts ... 
[SKIPPED]
Dumping lfs objects ... 
[SKIPPED]
Dumping container registry images ... 
[DISABLED]
Creating backup archive: 1477496735_gitlab_backup.tar ... done
Uploading backup archive to remote storage  ... skipped
Deleting tmp directories ... done
done
Deleting old backups ... skipping
Unpacking gitlab-ce (8.13.1-ce.0) over (8.11.2-ce.1) ...
Setting up gitlab-ce (8.13.1-ce.0) ...

[33m
       *.                  *.
      ***                 ***
     *****               *****
    .******             *******
    ********            ********
   ,,,,,,,,,***********,,,,,,,,,
  ,,,,,,,,,,,*********,,,,,,,,,,,
  .,,,,,,,,,,,*******,,,,,,,,,,,,
      ,,,,,,,,,*****,,,,,,,,,.
         ,,,,,,,****,,,,,,
            .,,,***,,,,
                ,*,.
[31m
     _______ __  __          __
    / ____(_) /_/ /   ____ _/ /_
   / / __/ / __/ /   / __ `/ __ \
  / /_/ / / /_/ /___/ /_/ / /_/ /
  \____/_/\__/_____/\__,_/_.___/
[0;10m

gitlab: Thank you for installing GitLab!
gitlab: To configure and start GitLab, RUN THE FOLLOWING COMMAND:

sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure

gitlab: GitLab should be reachable at https://whuang.spimag.com:8443
gitlab: Otherwise configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file
gitlab: And running reconfigure again.
gitlab: 
gitlab: For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme
gitlab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md
gitlab: 
Shutting down all GitLab services except those needed for migrations
ok: down: gitlab-workhorse: 1s, normally up
ok: down: logrotate: 0s, normally up
ok: down: nginx: 1s, normally up
ok: down: postgresql: 0s, normally up
ok: down: redis: 1s, normally up
ok: down: sidekiq: 0s, normally up
ok: down: unicorn: 0s, normally up
ok: run: postgresql: (pid 9906) 1s
ok: run: redis: (pid 9914) 0s
run: postgresql: (pid 9906) 1s; run: log: (pid 798) 2394s
run: redis: (pid 9914) 0s; run: log: (pid 799) 2394s
Reconfiguring GitLab to apply migrations
-.mount                                                                             loaded active mounted   /
[0m
================================================================================[0m
[31mError executing action `run` on resource 'bash[migrate gitlab-rails database]'[0m
================================================================================[0m

[0mMixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed[0m
------------------------------------[0m
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
[0m---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20161026-9928-qemdyd" ----
[0mSTDOUT: rake aborted!
[0mStandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
[0m
[0mPG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "priority" of relation "labels" already exists
[0m: ALTER TABLE "labels" ADD "priority" integer/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:407:in `add_column'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:434:in `add_column'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/postgresql_limit_fix.rb:6:in `add_column'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20160314094147_add_priority_to_label.rb:4:in `change'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:608:in `exec_migration'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
[0mActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "priority" of relation "labels" already exists
[0m: ALTER TABLE "labels" ADD "priority" integer
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:407:in `add_column'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:434:in `add_column'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/postgresql_limit_fix.rb:6:in `add_column'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20160314094147_add_priority_to_label.rb:4:in `change'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:608:in `exec_migration'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
[0mPG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "priority" of relation "labels" already exists
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:407:in `add_column'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:434:in `add_column'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/postgresql_limit_fix.rb:6:in `add_column'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20160314094147_add_priority_to_label.rb:4:in `change'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:608:in `exec_migration'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
[0m/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
[0mTasks: TOP => db:migrate
[0m(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[0m== 20160314094147 AddPriorityToLabel: migrating ===============================
[0m-- add_column(:labels, :priority, :integer)
[0mSTDERR: 
[0m---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20161026-9928-qemdyd" ----
[0mRan "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20161026-9928-qemdyd" returned 1[0m

[0mResource Declaration:[0m
---------------------[0m
# In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/database_migrations.rb
[0m
[0m 44: bash "migrate gitlab-rails database" do
[0m 45:   code <<-EOH
[0m 46:     set -e
[0m 47:     log_file="#{node['gitlab']['gitlab-rails']['log_directory']}/gitlab-rails-db-migrate-$(date +%s)-$$.log"
[0m 48:     umask 077
[0m 49:     /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:db:configure 2>& 1 | tee ${log_file}
[0m 50:     STATUS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
[0m 51:     echo $STATUS > #{db_migrate_status_file}
[0m 52:     exit $STATUS
[0m 53:   EOH
[0m 54:   environment ({'GITLAB_ROOT_PASSWORD' => initial_root_password }) if initial_root_password
[0m 55:   notifies :run, 'execute[enable pg_trgm extension]', :before unless OmnibusHelper.not_listening?("postgresql") || !node['gitlab']['postgresql']['enable']
[0m 56:   notifies :run, "execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache]", :immediately unless OmnibusHelper.not_listening?("redis")
[0m 57:   dependent_services.each do |svc|
[0m 58:     notifies :restart, svc, :immediately
[0m 59:   end
[0m 60:   not_if "(test -f #{db_migrate_status_file}) && (cat #{db_migrate_status_file} | grep -Fx 0)"
[0m 61:   only_if { node['gitlab']['gitlab-rails']['auto_migrate'] }
[0m 62: end
[0m
[0mCompiled Resource:[0m
------------------[0m
# Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/database_migrations.rb:44:in `from_file'
[0m
[0mbash("migrate gitlab-rails database") do
[0m  action [:run]
[0m  updated true
[0m  retries 0
[0m  retry_delay 2
[0m  default_guard_interpreter :default
[0m  command "migrate gitlab-rails database"
[0m  backup 5
[0m  returns 0
[0m  code "    set -e\n    log_file=\"/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-db-migrate-$(date +%s)-$$.log\"\n    umask 077\n    /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:db:configure 2>& 1 | tee ${log_file}\n    STATUS=${PIPESTATUS[0]}\n    echo $STATUS > /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-91f25c2\n    exit $STATUS\n"
[0m  interpreter "bash"
[0m  declared_type :bash
[0m  cookbook_name "gitlab"
[0m  recipe_name "database_migrations"
[0m  not_if "(test -f /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-91f25c2) && (cat /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status/db-migrate-873248b1f0d3a7a5535771a3a1635803-91f25c2 | grep -Fx 0)"
[0m  only_if { #code block }
[0mend
[0m
[0mPlatform:[0m
---------[0m
x86_64-linux[0m

[0m
```

I have been upgrading Gitlab 8.0 to 8.1 to 8.11, however, I have never seen this error before. Moreover, if I removed the files under `/var/opt/gitalb`, it works but all the existed data is lost. So, what can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these kinds of errors may due to database schema changes from version to version. FYI, you are using a OmniBus installation. Try `sudo gitlab-rake db:migrate` to adapt to the latest database schema.